# How to add leading 0's to different values in same column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-apply

I have a column that has values of length 5,6,8, or 9. The column should just have values of length 6 or 9. I need to add leading 0's if the value is of length 5 or 8.

There is another column which can identfy if the value should be 6 or 9 digits (indicator). An indicator value of 'Red' means 6 digits, and an indicator of 'Green' means 9 digits.

```
df['digits'] = df[df['indicator'] == 'red']['digits'].apply(lambda x: "{:006d}".format(x))
df['digits'] = df[df['indicator'] == 'green']['digits'].apply(lambda x: "{:009d}".format(x))


id    indicator     digits
0     red           54324
1     red           654345
2     green         533345678
3     green         56438594
```

expected result:

```
id    indicator     digits
0     red           054324  # 0 added to this value
1     red           654345
2     green         533345678
3     green         056438594 # 0 added to this value
```

I am getting an error of `ValueError: Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'float'`. Any ideas why? What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you the type of your `digits` column is `float`, you need to change it to `int`.

Also, `lambda x: "{:006d}".format(x)` is just `"{:006d}".format`:

```
df['digits'] = df[df['indicator'] == 'red']['digits'].astype(int).apply("{:006d}".format)
```

Comment: I get an error of `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead` however, I cannot seem to get this to work using `.loc`. Is this operation possible with loc?

Comment: @MartyB Use `df.loc[df['indicator'] == 'red', 'digits']`

Comment: Note that the column `dtype` will be converted into `object` from `int` or `float`

Comment: I guess what I am confused on is where the `"{:006d}".format`  would go using `.loc`

Comment: i got it with your help! `df.loc[df['indicator'] == 'red', 'digits'] = df['digits'].apply({:006d}".format`